# Xpath query for event filtering

Tags: xpath, event-log

I have the current filtering logic to define events that I want to source

```
<QueryList>
      <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
        <Select Path="Security">
    *[System[(EventID=4624 or EventID=4625)]]
   and
    *[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName'] != 'ANONYMOUS LOGON']]
   and
    *[substring([EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName']]],2,1) != '-']

   </Select>
      </Query>
   </QueryList>
```

But THe part "*[substring([EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName']]],2,1) != '-']" is leading to error as it is not being parsed.

I want to discard certain target usernames which start with 'L-' and 'D-' and 'C:/'.

Please suggest proper solutions

Comment: I can help if you provide an example of the XML you are parsing and what the desired out come of the xpath.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing, based on how you wrote your third XPath expression, that you have a structure like this:

```
...
<Any-Element>
    <EventData>L-username
        <Data Name='TargetUserName'>xxx</Data>
    </EventData>
</Any-Element>
...
```

Then you could use this expression to obtain what you want:

```
*[substring(EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName']], 2, 1) = '-']
```

But I suspect this is not the case, since your second expression compares the contents of the `<Data>` element (and not the contents of `<EventData>`, and you didn't mention it was failing. So probably the `xxx`string above is where your username is. If that is the case, you should compare the contents of `Data`, and not `EventData`:

```
*[EventData[substring(Data[@Name='TargetUserName'], 2, 1) = '-']]
```

Comment: Getting the error again.
Error - Last retry time: 26-05-2014 12:18:55. Code (0x138C): <f:ProviderFault provider="Event Forwarding Plugin" path="%systemroot%\system32\wevtfwd.dll" xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault"><t:ProviderError xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/windows/EventLog">Windows Event Forward plugin can't read any event from the query since the query returns no active channel. Please check channels in the query and make sure they exist and you have access to them.</t:ProviderError></f:ProviderFault>  Next retry time: 26-05-2014 12:23:55.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you change the query to pull application or system logs that you do not get the same error. There seems to be a bug with the Security logs. Another post suggests that reducing the character length to under 150 seems to resolve the issue.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cda721cc-6479-4b04-9fdd-9ccbec86b159/possible-bug-collecting-security-events-using-event-subscriptions-and-windows-2008-r2?forum=winserverManagement

Not sure if this solves your problem as you may need more than 150 characters.